# On the subgroup generated by a part of a group

Tags: group-theory

I am reading *Undergraduate Algebra*, by S.Lang. I can't understand the bold part of the following paragraph:

There is a general way of obtaining subgroups from a group. Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$, having at least one element. Let $H$ be the set of elements of $G$ consisting of all products $x_1\cdots x_n$ such that $x_i$ or $x_i^{-1}$ is an element of $S$ for each $i$, **and also containing the unit element**. Then $H$ is obviously a subgroup of $G$, called the subgroup generated by $S$.

My thoughts: if $x$ is in $S$, then $x\cdot x^{-1}=1$ is in $H$, so why to explicitely require the presence of $1$ in $H$?

Comment: You are right, that is not necessary. In fact an empty product is conventionally defined to equal the group identity, so you do not even need to insist that $S$ is non-empty. The empty set generates the subgroup consisting of the identity only.